# to-do-list web application in Django?

Tags: django, web-services, list

Is it possible to make a to-do-list web application in Django in which the admin sets the things to do and the user are only allowed to see what the admin put in their profiles? Which could be the steps to reach this goal? (example: first create admin, user and things model then...) thank you for your help!!

Comment: please can we discuss the basic steps? just to have an idea on how to start. I'm a begineer.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for that, sorry. We can't give you the whole steps

Comment: The todo list app is very well explained in this tutorial : http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html

Answer (score 1):

Not really the place for this open question on stack, however here a step by step tutorial on just what you are after.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/intro-to-django-building-a-to-do-list/